# JMeter if controller on HTTP response code

Tags: jmeter

I would like for some branch of the test to execute only if the response code from a previous sample returns with a certain HTTP code 200.

I tried the following as the condition to the 'if controller':

```
"{httpCode}"== "200"
```

but no luck (and no luck debugging it, debug sampler says nothing)

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Did you extract response code to variable httpCode beforehand? Use regex extractor for it http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor

Then check value of variable like that:

```
${__javaScript(${httpCode}=="200")}
```

Alternatively, you may use assertion, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11669393/808594

Comment: Hi. I have a regex extractor, which does the job (I can see 'httpCode=200' in the result tree). I tried your suggestion above, as well as just ${httpCode}=="200" - didn't seem to work. What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, I have one more insight. My if controller works.. The problem is that I'm trying to extract something depending on the result code. But it seems that if I put the extractor inside the if controller - it no longer has the original result (I'm using JSONPath to extract something).

Comment: It sounds really confusing, does you JSONPath extractor works without if controller? Try to put extractor (or multiple extractors) before if controller and then use it's result depending on httpCode.

Comment: Seems like JSONPath extractor cannot get access to the response within an if.

Answer (score 4):

I guess that you just missing `$` sign before variable.

Also JMeter exposes a variable called ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} which can be true or false. I'd recommend using it instead in your If controller.

Just put `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` variable into [IF Controller and get pie.](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie)

Answer (score 1):

Add the HTTP request inside the "IF Controller" to which all request you want to check the previous result condition and define the following inbuilt JavaScript condition '“${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}”'.